# findViewById returns nullpointerexception in Recycler View Adapter android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a recycler view and my reference to the image and text view which am fetching with findViewById returns null.

I have tried to change the ids and severally change the image and text but no avail and I have been debugging all day

**Please help me because as a new learner it is very frustrating**

**Activity_Main**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
    package com.example.jayrecyc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        ArrayList<users> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));
        list.add(new users(R.drawable.whatsapp,"Jay Patel"));

        adapter ad = new adapter(list,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ad);

        LinearLayoutManager lym = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lym);





    }
}
```

**Adapter class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.util.ArrayList;


public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.viewHolder>{

    ArrayList<users> lis;
    Context context;

    public adapter(ArrayList<users> lis, Context context) {
        this.lis = lis;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.itemslayout,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( viewHolder holder, int position) {
        users use = lis.get(position);
        // holder uses
        holder.imgj.setImageResource(use.getPic());
        holder.tv.setText(use.getT());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lis.size();
    }



    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imgj;
        TextView tv;
        public viewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgj = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }

}
```

**Modal Class**

```
public class users {

    int pic;
    String t;

    public users(int pic, String t) {
        this.pic = pic;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public int getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(int pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public String getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: change this line: recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); to this: recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

Comment: Thx it was small mistake not able to recognise

Comment: You need to call as recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) instead of recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)